# Generic way to only slideToggle() child div

Tags: javascript, jquery

New to jquery. I want to do a slideToggle to accordion collaps and expand a section.

When clicking the header, I want to expand/collapse everything in "#section".

```
<h3 id="assignments">Assignments</h3>
    <div id="section">
      Assignment Count <input type="number" name="assignment_count">
    </div>
```

I have the code that works below. But I want to make it generic so that if I have any header I click, it will only collapse the section below it and not all div's with an id of "#section"

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("h3").click(function(){
        $("#section").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) which gets the immediately following sibling.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("h3").click(function(){
        $(this).next("#section").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Also, since you want to make it **generic** do not use IDs. Use classes instead. Something like this

```
<h3 class="assignments">Assignments</h3>
<div class="section">
  Assignment Count <input type="number" name="assignment_count">
</div> 

$("h3").click(function(){
  $(this).next(".section").slideToggle();
});
```

```js
$("h3").click(function() {
  $(this).next(".section").slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3 class="assignments">Assignments 1</h3>
<div class="section">
  Assignment Count
  <input type="number" name="assignment_count" />
</div>

<h3 class="assignments">Assignments 2</h3>
<div class="section">
  Assignment Count
  <input type="number" name="assignment_count" />
</div>

<h3 class="assignments">Assignments 3</h3>
<div class="section">
  Assignment Count
  <input type="number" name="assignment_count" />
</div>

<h3 class="assignments">Assignments 4</h3>
<div class="section">
  Assignment Count
  <input type="number" name="assignment_count" />
</div>
```

Comment: `#section` in the selector kind of negates the 'generic' idea though.

Comment: Yes it does, but it works close enough.  Thanks a ton @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: True, I just wanted to show how `next()` can be used and then make a suggestion to use classes.

Answer (score 2):

You can use DOM traversal to achieve this. In the `click` handler for the `h3`, the `next()` function can be used to retrieve the following element. Try this:

```js
$('h3').click(function() {
  $(this).next('div').slideToggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Assignments</h3>
<div>
  Assignment Count
  <input type="number" name="assignment_count">
</div>

<h3>Foo</h3>
<div>
  Foo Count
  <input type="number" name="foo_count">
</div>

<h3>Bar</h3>
<div id="section">
  Bar Count
  <input type="number" name="bar_count">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

using :header you can trigger "on" click event on any header say h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(":header").on('click',function(){
        $(this).nextUntil(":header").slideToggle();
    });
}); 



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1 id="assignments1">Assignment1</h1>
    <div id="section">
      Assignment Count <input type="number" name="assignment_count">
    </div>
 <h2 id="assignments2">Assignments2</h2>       
    <div id="section">
      Assignment Count <input type="number" name="assignment_count">
    </div>
 <h3 id="assignments3">Assignments3</h3>       
 <div id="section">
      Assignment Count <input type="number" name="assignment_count">
    </div>
```